# Python Requests Self Signed Cert

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I know there are multiple older threads on this, but none of the solutions mentioned on it have worked for me.
I'm trying to use a self-signed cert. On my test machine, I have a added private CA, whose `ca.pem` to `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ca.crt` and when I run `curl https://example.com:80000/health`, I get a valid output.

I wish to do the same using Python. I am using Python 3.10.12.
`certifi.where()` is `/home/normal/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem`

The error I'm facing is:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='example.com', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /health (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1007)')))
```

I've tried multiple things such as:

Setting `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` path

```
ca_path = os.path.join(
    '/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/',
    'ca.crt')
print(ca_path)
os.environ['REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE'] = ca_path
```

Setting verify to private CA path

```
response = requests.post(url, verify=ca_path)
```

Setting verify to cert path

```
response = requests.post(url, verify=certifi.where())
```

Creating a fullchain.pem file and setting verify to said path

```
cat cert.pem > fullchain.pem
cat ca.pem >> fullchain.pem
response = requests.post(url, verify='./fullchain.pem')
```

Going to the path shown from `certifi.where()` and appending `ca.pem` and `cert.pem` to it

```
cd /home/<usr>/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/certifi

cp cacert.pem cacert.pem.bak
cat cacert.pem.bak <(echo) ca.pem <(echo) cert.pem > cacert.pem
```

Ideally I would like to be able to do it in such a fashion, that I can use Azure functions to run my Python code.

Comment: Maybe show how you generated the cert?

Comment: I realized my mistake. When creating the bundle, a newline is needed between the 2 certs.
so 
echo "" >> cacert.pem
cat ca.pem >> cacert.pem
echo "" >> cacert.pem
cat cert.pem >> cacert.pem

response = requests.post(url, verify=certifi.where())


One can also use requests.post(url, verify='./certificate_bundle.pem') which can be created like above too.

Answer (score 0):

I realized my mistake. When creating the bundle, a newline is needed between the 2 certs. so

```
echo "" >> cacert.pem cat ca.pem >> cacert.pem echo "" >> cacert.pem cat cert.pem >> cacert.pem response = requests.post(url, verify=certifi.where())
```

One can also use

```
requests.post(url, verify='./certificate_bundle.pem')
```

which can be created like above too.